# DockerHub autobuild for a GitHub pull request - using the $DOCKER_TAG variable?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a project with DockerHub autobuilds running for each branch of the project.  These builds are running nicely.

I would like to extend this autobuild configuration to build images for selected pull requests for these branches.

[image]

The following documentation indicates that a variable named DOCKER_TAG should be available in a DockerHub autobuild.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#environment-variables-for-building-and-testing

I want to configure my auto build in the following manner.

If I attempt to build a tag named "pr1234" then my build will overlay the code from PR #1234 before running the build.

```
# Assign the env variable DOCKER_TAG to an arg of the same name
ARG DOCKER_TAG=${DOCKER_TAG}

...

# if DOCKER_TAG is in the format prNNNN then merge code for that PR on top of the current branch
RUN PRNUM=`echo ${DOCKER_TAG}| egrep "^pr([0-9]+)$" | sed -e s/pr//` && \
    if [ -n "$PRNUM" ]; \ 
    then echo "Merging $PRNUM"; \
      curl -o /tmp/pr.patch -L https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/pull/$PRNUM.diff; \
      git apply /tmp/pr.patch; \
    fi
```

If I run my build locally, I am able to set this variable and my docker build runs as I would like.

```
docker build -t dspace/dspace:pr1234 -f Dockerfile.jdk8-test --build-arg DOCKER_TAG=pr1234 .
```

When I attempt to run this from Dockerhub, the DOCKER_TAG variable appears to be blank, so I presume that DOCKER_TAG is not being set as I expected.

Can you suggest a way to access this variable or to accomplish an automated build for selected PR's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work.  I created a build hook named **hooks/build** and pass the variable explicitly.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build --build-arg DOCKER_TAG=$DOCKER_TAG -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH -t $IMAGE_NAME .
```

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#custom-build-phase-hooks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps me out the issue.